# FirebaseでのAuthenticationの際にメールアドレスを使用しない方法

Tags: firebase, flutter

現在モバイルアプリの作成を行う中で認証にFirebaseのAuthenticationを使用しています。
その中で必ずメールアドレスの登録を促され、IDにメールアドレスを登録する仕様となっているのですが、
個人情報保護の観点からメールアドレスの保持をやめ、IDに別の文字列を使用したいです。

Authenticationではメールアドレスでの登録以外はできないのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考サイト https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?hl=ja

Comment: 個人情報保護の観点も大事ですが、実際は個人を特定しておかないと不正な利用や何かしら法律に触れるような利用をされたときの対応できない可能性があります。それを踏まえて考えるとよいでしょう。